# Solving series using ratio test

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am given the following:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{{(n+2)}^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} 
$$

I used ratio test to get to this:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{{(n+2+1)}^{n+1+1}}{(n+1+1)!}  . \frac{(n+1)!}{{(n+2)}^{n+1}} 
$$

But then am stuck at continuing from this.I am having problem with dividing  ${{(n+2+1)}^{n+1+1}}$ with ${{(n+2)}^{n+1}}$.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note each term of your series exceeds $1$.

Comment: Use the fact that $\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n+2)!}=\dfrac{1}{n+2}$. Then, you have $\dfrac{(n+3)^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}\cdot\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n+2)^{n+1}}=\dfrac{(n+3)^{n+2}}{(n+2)^{n+2}}$. I don't know if this simplifies the problem or not.

Comment: @DavidMitra So its $ {({n+2})^1} $?

Comment: I meant, you don't need to use the Ratio Test. The series diverges since its terms do not approach zero.

Comment: @DavidMitra Yup they have indicated that we can use the divergence test or ratio test, but i want to know how to solve this using the ratio test and specifically the division part, so that i can use it to solve other problems

Answer (score 1):

Now you can write this as $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{n+3}{n+2}\bigg)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{n+3}{n+2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{3}{n})^n}{(1+\frac{2}{n})^n}\cdot\bigg(\frac{n+3}{n+2}\bigg)^2=\frac{e^3}{e^2}\cdot1=e,$

or use $m=n+2$ to get

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{n+3}{n+2}\bigg)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{n+3}{n+2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{n+3}{n+2}\bigg)^{n+2}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{m+1}{m}\bigg)^m=\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{m}\bigg)^m=e$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, thanks to the Stirling Formula:
$$
\log \frac{{(n+2)}^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = (n+1) \log(n+2) - \log (n+1)! \sim n
$$
So your series is divergent.

Comment: Sorry, but we are supposed to use ratio test :(